How to calculate the memory for quantum circuit?
How much memory is required to simulate the quantum circuit with 36 qubits? How do I calculate it?

Have you looked here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11643/29979? River's answer contains a formula to calculate the memory for a general circuit with no pre-known information.
